# video download from google+/picasa android

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-plus, picasa

We have a requirement to download video from google+/picasa and store it into sdcard. 
Can you please any one help me to solve this issue?
google+/picasa

[image]

Converting from `URI` to `byte[]`, then `byte[]` is stored to file:

```
InputStream videoStream = getActivity().getContentResolver().openInputStream(videoUri);
byte bytes[] = ByteStreams.toByteArray(videoStream );
videoFile = new File("abcd.mp4");
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(videoFile);
out.write(bytes);
out.close();
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Please check the edited code. Now video is stored in sdcard but not played... :(

Answer (score 0):

Can you try that one :

```
public String DownloadFromUrl(String DownloadUrl, String fileName) {

File SDCardRoot = null;
try {
    SDCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File files = new File(SDCardRoot+fileName);
    int sizeoffile;
    if(!files.exists()) 
    {
        File root = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();               

        File dir = new File (root.getAbsolutePath());
        if(dir.exists()==false) {
            dir.mkdirs();
        }

        URL url = new URL(DownloadUrl);
        File file = new File(dir, fileName);

        /* Open a connection to that URL. */
        URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();
        sizeoffile = ucon.getContentLength();
        Log.d("SIZEOFFILE: ", sizeoffile+" BYTE");
        /*
         * Define InputStreams to read from the URLConnection.
         */
        InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);

        /*
         * Read bytes to the Buffer until there is nothing more to read(-1).
         */
        ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(5000);
        int current = 0;
        while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
            baf.append((byte) current);
        }
        /* Convert the Bytes read to a String. */
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        fos.write(baf.toByteArray());
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
    }
}
catch (IOException e) {
    e.getMessage();
}

return SDCardRoot+fileName; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Finally i found the solution.



 Uri videoUri = data.getData();
                    File videoFile = null;
                    final InputStream imageStream;
                    try {
                        imageStream = getActivity().getContentResolver().openInputStream(videoUri);
                        byte bytes[] = ByteStreams.toByteArray(imageStream);//IStoByteArray(imageStream);
                        videoFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+    "/"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".mp4");
                        videoFile.createNewFile();
                        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(videoFile);
                        out.write(bytes);
                        out.close();
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }catch (Exception ee){
                        ee.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have recently encountered this.

I first discovered that what I'm receiving is a **picture** rather than a video.

But I didn't understand why Facebook is successfully playing the online video I shared via (Google+'s) Photo.

I then occasionally discovered that the file they're currently giving is a **GIF** with the original extension in the `MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME` section of the contentUri.

Eeek!